# I am getting error while I was trying to get file from firebase storage

Tags: python, firebase, attributeerror

I Was making face recognition attendance system and if it detect face it will display their name Pic.... So I stored the image in firebase storage in order to get the image from the storage I use this code

```
blob = bucket.get_blob(f'Images/{id}.png')
                array = np.frombuffer(blob.download_as_string(), np.uint8)
                imgStudent = cv2.imdecode(array, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
```

it was working for a while but now it kept saying error that says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download_as_string'`  so how do I fix this?

I have tried everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the file format that you have added in the firebase, as it is checking for the format with .png so it would give output as NoneType for other formats.

Answer (score 0):

First check the image format. I was trying with .png format. Then suddenly I realised my images are in .jpg format.

Also you can try below code if it's not working:

```
blob = bucket.get_blob(f'Images/{id}.png')
if blob is not None:
    array = np.frombuffer(blob.download_as_string(), np.uint8)
    imgStudent = cv2.imdecode(array, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
else:
    print(f"Blob 'Images/{id}.png' not found.")
```